# Ruby Zip: Cannot open entry for reading while its open for writing

Tags: ruby, docx

I'm trying to write some mail merge code where I open a `docx` file (as a zip) replace tags with data and then create a new `docx` file (as a zip) and iterate over the old zip file either adding my new replaced data or pulling the existing file from the old `docx` file and adding that instead.

The problem I'm getting is anytime I try to access the `out.get_output_stream` method, I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot open entry for reading while its open for writing - [Content_Types].xml (StandardError)
```

`[Content_Types].xml` happens to be first file in the `docx` so that's why its bombing on that particular file. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip' # rubyzip gem

class WordMailMerge
  def self.open(path, &block)
    self.new(path, &block)
  end

  def initialize(path, &block)
    @replace = {}
    if block_given?
      @zip = Zip::File.open(path)
      yield(self)
      @zip.close
    else
      @zip = Zip::File.open(path)
    end
  end

  def force_settings
    @replace["word/settings.xml"] = %{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:settings xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main"><w:zoom w:percent="100"/></w:settings>}
  end

  def merge(rec)
    xml = @zip.read("word/document.xml")

    # replace tags with correct content

    @replace["word/document.xml"] = xml
  end

  def save(path)
    Zip::File.open(path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |out|
      @zip.each do |entry|

        if @replace[entry.name]
          # this line creates the error
          out.get_output_stream(entry.name).write(@replace[entry.name])
        else
          # this line also will do it.
          out.get_output_stream(entry.name).write(@zip.read(entry.name))
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def close
    @zip.close
  end
end

w = WordMailMerge.open("Option_2.docx")
w.force_settings
w.merge({})
w.save("Option_2_new.docx")
```

The following is the stack trace:

```
/home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/delegate.rb:85:in `call': cannot open entry for reading while its open for writing - [Content_Types].xml (StandardError)
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/delegate.rb:85:in `method_missing'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/streamable_stream.rb:28:in `get_input_stream'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/streamable_stream.rb:45:in `write_to_zip_output_stream'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:313:in `block (3 levels) in commit'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:38:in `block in each'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:37:in `each'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:37:in `each'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:312:in `block (2 levels) in commit'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/output_stream.rb:53:in `open'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:311:in `block in commit'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:409:in `block in on_success_replace'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tmpdir.rb:130:in `create'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:407:in `on_success_replace'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:310:in `commit'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:334:in `close'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:103:in `ensure in open'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:103:in `open'
    from zip.rb:34:in `save'
    from zip.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace instead of just message

Comment: @TarunLalwani done.

Comment: Not needed now, please have a look at the answer, I was able to reproduce and fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your update code to below

```
  def save(path)
    Zip::File.open(path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |out|
      @zip.each do |entry|

        if @replace[entry.name]
          # this line creates the error
          out.get_output_stream(entry.name){ |f| f.puts @replace[entry.name] }
        else
          # this line also will do it.
          # out.get_output_stream(entry.name).write(@zip.read(entry.name))
          out.get_output_stream(entry.name){ |f|  f.puts @zip.read(entry.name) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

And then the file will get created

**Edit-1**

Below is the final code that I had used for testing

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip' # rubyzip gem

class WordMailMerge
  def self.open(path, &block)
    self.new(path, &block)
  end

  def initialize(path, &block)
    @replace = {}
    if block_given?
      @zip = Zip::File.open(path)
      yield(self)
      @zip.close
    else
      @zip = Zip::File.open(path)
    end
  end

  def force_settings
    @replace["word/settings.xml"] = %{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:settings xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main"><w:zoom w:percent="100"/></w:settings>}
  end

  def merge(rec)
    xml = @zip.read("word/document.xml")

    # replace tags with correct content

    @replace["word/document.xml"] = xml.gsub("{name}", "Tarun lalwani")
  end

  def save(path)
    Zip::File.open(path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |out|
      @zip.each do |entry|

        if @replace[entry.name]
          # this line creates the error
          out.get_output_stream(entry.name){ |f| f.puts @replace[entry.name] }
        else
          # this line also will do it.
          # out.get_output_stream(entry.name).write(@zip.read(entry.name))
          out.get_output_stream(entry.name){ |f|  f.puts @zip.read(entry.name) }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def close
    @zip.close
  end
end

w = WordMailMerge.open("Option_2.docx")
w.force_settings
w.merge({})
w.save("Option_2_new.docx")
```

**Option_2.docx**

[image: Old doc]

**Option_2_new.doc**

[image: Updated document]

Comment: Im getting a new error now:

`/home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@appt/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/file.rb:248:in `get_output_stream': cannot open stream to directory entry - 'word/' (ArgumentError)
 from zip.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in save'` I can't post the whole stack trace because its too long. Looks like its bombing on a directory. Maybe I have to do something different to create directories inside zip files?

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you on? I tested on Ruby 2.5 and I was able to even see the replaced value in the word document

Comment: Tested on `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]` also

Comment: 2.4.1p111 Let me take your entire code file and try that by itself. All I did was fix the two lines in the save function so far.

Comment: Im getting the exact error I got in the above comment re: the directory entry.

Comment: Can you remove the old `RubyZip` and install it again. Also I would just create a new word document again and test

Comment: Ok using your word document worked. So now I need to figure out why my Word Document isn't working. Thanks for your help!